# Yii2 formatting boolean field in GridView

Tags: yii2

I remember to have done this before, but now it does not work and I can't get it out.

```
[
    'label' => 'Sex',
    'attribute' => 'gan_sex',
    'filter' => [
        '1' => 'Male',
        '2' => 'Female'
    ]
],
```

The output is

```
1
2
2
1
```

instead of

```
Male
Female
Female
Male
```

What is the problem now? I'd swear I used it just the same way but ...

Comment: the code seems right .. check for filterModel ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it like this

```
[
    'label' => 'Sex',
    'attribute' => 'gan_sex',
    'filter' => [
        '1' => 'Male',
        '2' => 'Female'
    ],
    // translate lookup value
    'value' => function ($model) {
      $gender = [
        '1' => 'Male',
        '2' => 'Female'
      ];
      return $gender[$model->gan_sex];
    }
]
```

Possible values for gan_sex must be restricted to 1 and 2.